# Can't propagate exit code

Tags: slimerjs

I try to exit from the my `javascript` code like this:

```
slimer.exit(1);
```

But I don't get the 1 exit code. I try even:

```
slimer.exit(2);
```

I get exit code 0 forever.

Any idea/help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight from the [documentation](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/api/slimer.html)... (emphasis mine)

> exit()
>
> It stops the script and SlimerJS exit.
>
> **It accepts an optional exit code but it is ignored because of a
>   limitation in Firefox/XulRunner.**
>
> `slimer.exit();`

The exit code is ignored. This is a known issue in slimerJS.

Comment: First, Thanks man! Second, WTF?!?!?! Why it works like this?!?!?!?!

Comment: @gran It's a bug they're aware of :). One of the packages they use ([XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner)) has a limitation where it can't return an exit status code. It may or may not be fixed, one day! If this answer helped, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - thanks!

Comment: This bug force me to not use slimerJS :/